# Animating UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell using facebook POP framework

Tags: ios, facebook, uicollectionview, facebook-pop

I am using POP framework to achieve HomeScreen Animation in facebook paper app(i.e posts with horizontal scrolling when user pans the posts it grows dynamically and settles to full screen),may i know how to achieve this and what are the views(i.e scrollview or collectionview) i have to use to achieve that animation.
Any Help appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you have tried already

Comment: tried with uicollectionview,but not able to increase and decrease the cells height proportionally with pan geture.